# How to extract errors on fitted slopes using R's bfast?

Tags: r, time-series

I am using bfast in R to fit time series.  I need to extract the slopes *and errors* on the slopes for each segment that it finds.  I figured out the former but not the latter.  Here's how I got the slopes:

```
fit<-bfast(my_ts,season="none",max.iter=2)
plot(fit,type="trend")

niter<-length(fit$output)
slopes<-coef(fit$output[[niter]]$bp.Vt)[,2]
slopes
```

but I can't seem to find a way to get the errors on the slopes.  I found someone's suggestion to use

```
 plot(fit,type="trend",ANOVA=T)
```

instead of just plot(fit), but a) apparently, it only prints out the slopes + error on the graph and I need to output them to a file, and b) it doesn't work for me anyway, as I get:

```
Error in out$bp.Wt$datatsp : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
In addition: Warning message:
In anova.lm(model) :
   ANOVA F-tests on an essentially perfect fit are unreliable
```

Your help would be appreciated!

Comment: `?bfast   #No documentation for ‘bfast’ in specified packages and libraries:`

Comment: The package is here: http://bfast.r-forge.r-project.org

Comment: That information belongs in the body of your question. Please do the needed editing. And also provide code that creates something like the time series you are using, noting that there are multiple types of R time series.